# JavaFX16 WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @***'

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I am trying to run JavaFX16 Application using OpenJDK16 (the application itself was written via Java 1.8). Unfortunately, every time running my application I receive the following WARNING message:

*--- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) @ ListPlanWizard ---
апр. 14, 2021 12:46:53 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @1cebc698'*

**Could you explain why I'm getting it and how can I avoid this, please?**

- Please note, that unlike the other issues with this or similar
  warnings which I've found in the Internet my application doesn't
  crash after this or something and works as intended.
- Also please note that I use the hint from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing) to avoid
  *Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application*
- I don't use external JavaFX OpenSDK or something in my project's properties.

My pom.xml document is attached below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>bla.blabla</groupId>
    <artifactId>ListPlanWizard</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.3</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ListPlanWizard</name>
    <description>blablablablabla</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <start-class>bla.blabla.ListPlanWizard.Crutch</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used to work with the older excel file format - .xls -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used to work with the newer excel file format - .xlsx -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>bla.blabla.ListPlanWizard.Crutch</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <excludeDevtools>true</excludeDevtools>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thank you for the answers in advance!

Comment: no screenshots of text please .. instead c&p the text

Comment: the first thing I notice is that in properties you got java version 1.8, but you are using OpenJDK16

Comment: This is a new thing in JavaFX 16—see [JDK-8256362](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8256362). The general fix is to place the JavaFX modules on the module-path and to ensure they are resolved as modules (e.g. if your code isn't modular you may need to use `--add-modules`). Though note having JavaFX on the module-path does not require that _your code_ be modular. Unfortunately, I don't know what the fix would be while using Maven (hence a comment rather than answer).

Comment: @Dahlin as I have mentioned in the question post the application was written via java 1.8, but now I use OpenJDK16. However, the Source/Binary Format of the app remains the same.

Comment: @Slaw thank you for the comment, it shed some light on the situation a bit. However, since Java 1.8 doesn't support modules yet then the answer is going to be something like upgrade the Java version to 9+ or downgrade the version of JavaFX to 15-.

Comment: If you're using Java 8 then you can't use JavaFX 9+ as those versions are compiled with a version of Java newer than Java 8 (JavaFX 11-16 are all (cross?) compiled to Java 11). But in your other comment you say you're using OpenJDK 16 which means you _are not_ using Java 8 and modules are in fact supported. Though note again, just because you have JavaFX on the module-path does not mean that _your code_ needs to be modular.

Comment: You could also just igore this warning. It is not harmful.

Comment: Important Changes
JavaFX runtime logs a warning if javafx.* modules are loaded from the classpath
https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/doc-files/release-notes-16.md

Comment: @GunnarBernstein so How to fix this warning?

Comment: @Jawad El Fou: I gave up. Tried answer of SANISH, but this did not change a thing. The bug thread was not to helpful either. I switched back to JavaFX 15.

Comment: @GunnarBernstein I am going  to that I guess, its a shame

Answer (score 0):

```
    // For Gradle .... 
   // Add the code in your 'build.gradle'.
   // Javafx modules will be fetched from classpath...
  // No warnings thereafter..
    run   {
            doFirst   {
                jvmArgs   =   [
                        '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                        '--add-modules', 'javafx.controls',
                        '--add-modules', 'javafx.fxml',
                        '--add-modules', 'javafx.graphics',
                        '--add-modules', 'javafx.base',
                        '--add-modules', 'javafx.swing',
                ]
            }
        }
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please provide a summary of how your answer solves the problem and why it may be preferable to the other answers provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the magical incantations that fixed the problem for me:

- I have ***not*** downloaded any javafx SDK.
- I do ***not*** use `javafx-maven-plugin`.
- I use only two javafx modules: `javafx.swing` and `javafx.web`.
- These two modules need the following additional modules: `javafx-controls`, `javafx-media`, `javafx-graphics`, and `javafx-basic`.
- I include `javafx.swing` and `javafx.web` as plain maven dependencies, as follows:

(in pom.xml)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>19-ea+3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>19-ea+3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then, I run my app with the following JVM arguments:

`--add-modules=javafx.swing,javafx.web --module-path=$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$\org\openjfx\javafx-web\19-ea+3\javafx-web-19-ea+3.jar;$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$\org\openjfx\javafx-web\19-ea+3\javafx-web-19-ea+3-win.jar;$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\19-ea+3\javafx-controls-19-ea+3.jar;$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\19-ea+3\javafx-controls-19-ea+3-win.jar;$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$\org\openjfx\javafx-media\19-ea+3\javafx-media-19-ea+3.jar;$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$\org\openjfx\javafx-media\19-ea+3\javafx-media-19-ea+3-win.jar;$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$\org\openjfx\javafx-swing\19-ea+3\javafx-swing-19-ea+3.jar;$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$\org\openjfx\javafx-swing\19-ea+3\javafx-swing-19-ea+3-win.jar;$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\19-ea+3\javafx-graphics-19-ea+3.jar;$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\19-ea+3\javafx-graphics-19-ea+3-win.jar;$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$\org\openjfx\javafx-base\19-ea+3\javafx-base-19-ea+3.jar;$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$\org\openjfx\javafx-base\19-ea+3\javafx-base-19-ea+3-win.jar`

(Note that `'$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$'` is a macro provided by IntellijIdea for convenience. It expands to something like `~/.m2/repository`.)